# Cannot change axios heder content-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, error-handling, axios

I'm trying to send an error from nodejs server in the from of json, however the `error.response.date` of axios gives a string of html.

server:

```
throw {msg: "Fields must be filled", status: 422};
```

client:

```
axios
        .post("/api/posts/update?_method=PUT", {id, updatedFields}, {header: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}})
        .then(res=>{...})
        .catch(err=>{
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
        });
```

display:

```
//this is err.response.data
Error: 422: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Error</title> </head> <body> <pre>[object Object]</pre> </body> </html>
```

Comment: 'header: ' should be 'headers: ', to start with.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work

Comment: There might be other issues, that's why I didn't post an answer - just noticed that while glancing at it. Axios needs to receive "headers", "header" definitely won't work. Have you inspected in dev tools to be sure the header isn't being passed in the request?

Comment: Okay, it's fixed. it gives the right data

Comment: Good to hear it worked!

Comment: @EyePatch wish you had posted your solution here because I have a similar issue.

Comment: @shb2789 Im so sorry. I dont have the solution anymore. I should have posted it but I didn't. Im trying to think about it now and to remember it but no good.Again, Im sorry. Good luck